# How to change backgroundTint of odd numbered rows without stacked up rows?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `recycler-view` and I want the items on the odd-numbered rows to have darker tint, now I've managed to do this, in OnBindViewHolder, but the problem is that if I change the DataSet then there rows that stack-up on each other with the same color...

I've understood that if use `notifyDataSetChanged` then it should fix it, but as I've understood using `notifyDataSetChanged` is not efficient so I'm looking for better ways to fix it.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StandingsHolder holder, int position) {
        StandingsDetail currentStandingsDetail = standingsDetail.get(position);
        String playerName = (position+1) + " " + currentStandingsDetail.player.getFirstName() + " " + currentStandingsDetail.player.getLastName();
        holder.name.setText(playerName);
        holder.rating.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getRating()));
        holder.games.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getGames()));
        holder.wins.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getWins()));
        holder.losses.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getLosses()));
        holder.goals.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getGoals()));
        holder.assists.setText(String.valueOf(currentStandingsDetail.standings.getAssists()));
        if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dark_overlay)));
        }
    }
```

problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mr5C.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the background color explicitly for both the odd numbered rows and the even numbered rows.

This is important becasue a row which is recycled from an odd numbered row will have a dark background. If this row happens to be reused to show an even numbered row, you get the wrong background tint.